# Pick appropriate .rc file on language selection

Tags: c++, mfc, bootstrapper

In my MFC application,there are three resource files(.rc) for three different languages(jap,eng,russian) and one main.rc file which includes other three resource file.All resource files contains same resource string in different languages and they all includes same resource header resource.h.
When user runs the application ,popup window will appear asking user to select one language.Based on the user selection application has to select appropriate rc from which it will load resources.

Is there any way by which when user select one language application will pick appropriate resource file.

Comment: The operating system already knows what language the user prefers.  And he'll generally prefer to use the language bar if he likes to switch.  If you want to force the selection for some reason instead of leaving it up to the user then use SetThreadPreferredUILanguages().  Use SetThreadUILanguage() on XP.

Answer (score 3):

In the MFC this is done via satellite DLLs.

Place each language RC in a separate DLL. Than upon load of the application load the specific language DLL and use [AfxSetResourceHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/d8ws31ff.aspx) with this handle.

In this case resource are searched in this DLL.

Comment: I have only 10-15 resource strings in .rc file,nothing else.Creating DLLs for each .rc file does not make any sense.

Comment: @VishalChavan you could put your strings in different ranges in the same .rc file (e.g jap: 1000-1999, eng: 2000-2999, rus: 3000-3999) and depending on the language apply an offset to the id you are passing to LoadString.

Comment: I support the idea of Michael Walz. I know no way to do this inside one exe without having different ids.

Comment: @MichaelWalz that could be easier solution.  Thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to consider adding additional `stringtables` to your project.

More details are provided here:

http://www.dev102.com/2008/10/20/how-to-localize-your-application-using-string-tables/

Basically, you add an additional table and set the culture information in the resource editor. Then, you can specify that culture before getting the value.

The example provided is for C# but the principles are just the same.

A possible way forward if needed.